# Primes in quadratic number fields

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

If $p$ is a prime number such that $p≡3\;mod\;4$, prove that $\sqrt{-p}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[ ]{-p}]$ and in $\mathbb{Z}[\displaystyle\frac{1+\sqrt[ ]{-p}}{2}]$ too.

*Notes*

We have seen in class that if the norm is a prime then the element is irreducible.

I tried this: If $\sqrt[]{-p}$ is not a prime, then it means it factors in two other numbers of the form $\alpha=a+\sqrt{-p}\cdot b$ and $\beta=c+\sqrt{-p}\cdot d$, such that $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{-p}$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what is the norm of an element? Do you know that if the norm is a prime then the element is prime?

Comment: we have seen in class that if the norm is a prime then the element is irreducible...

Comment: I tried this: If $\sqrt[]{-p}$ is not a prime, then it means it factors in two other numbers of the form $\alpha=a+\sqrt{-p}\cdot b$ and $\beta=c+\sqrt{-p}\cdot d$, such that $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{-p}$.

Comment: Now what happens when you take the norm on both sides of that equation?

Comment: I tried this: If $\sqrt[]{-p}$ is not a prime, then it means it factors in two other numbers of the form $\alpha=a+\sqrt{-p}\cdot b$ and $\beta=c+\sqrt{-p}\cdot d$, such that $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{-p}$. I used the function norm, $N(a+b\sqrt[ ]{-p})=a^2+b^2p$ in the equality $\alpha\beta=\sqrt{-p}$ and we have: $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)=N(\sqrt{-p})=p$. Now $p$ is prime then irreducible.This implies that $N(\alpha)$ or $N(\beta)$ are units in $\mathbb{Z}$ and consequently $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[ ]{-p}]$. I do not know how to finish...

Answer (score 1):

Recall some facts:

> In a domain,  $x$ is a prime element if and only if $(x)$ is a prime ideal.

and

> $\Bbb{F}_p$, the field with $p$ elements, is the unique commutative ring with unity (up to isomorphism) with cardinality $p$.

Let's focus first on $R=\Bbb{Z}\left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{-p}}{2}\right]$. This is the ring of integers of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, so we can use the definition of norm of an element.

Note that $N_K(\sqrt{-p}) = \sqrt{-p}\cdot (-\sqrt{-p}) = p$, so $\sqrt{-p}$ is an irreducible element of $R$. But there's more. I hope you know what is the norm of an ideal in a ring of integers.

Consider the ideal $P=(\sqrt{-p}) \subset R$. You have that $N_K(P)=N_K(\sqrt{-p}) = p$, so $R/P$ is a ring with $p$ elements. But there is only one ring with $p$ elements, i.e. the finite field of order $p$, so $P$ is actually a maximal (hence prime) ideal. Using the fact above, this proves that $\sqrt{-p}$ is prime in $R$.

As for the other ring, call $Q = (\sqrt{-p}) \subset \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$. Clearly $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}] \subset R$ is an extension of rings, and $Q=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}] \cap P$. Now one has that $Q$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ applying the following proposition:

> Let $A\subset R$ be an extension of rings. If $P\subset R$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $P \cap A \subset A$ is a prime ideal of $A$.

This proves that $\sqrt{-p}$ is a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ as well.

Comment: I don´t know what is the norm of an ideal in a ring of integers. Could you give me another way to solve or explain to me what is the norm of an ideal in a ring of integers?

Comment: It's the cardinality of the quotient, and it is always finite. In the case that the ideal is principal, then the norm of the ideal coincides with the norm of any generator. These are quite basic theorems, maybe you will find out them in future. As for another approach, I have no idea on how solving this exercise without the norm of ideals. Sorry. Irreducibility is easy, but primality is not.

Comment: One more thing: I suppose that the norm, $N(a+b(\displaystyle\frac{1+\sqrt[ ]{-p}}{2}))=a^2+ab+b^2(\displaystyle\frac{1+p}{4})$ for $a,b \in{\mathbb{Z}}$, but how do you calculate $N(\sqrt[ ]{-p})$?

Comment: Another definition of norm is $$N_K(a) = \sigma_1(a) \cdots \sigma_n(a)$$ where the $\sigma_i$ are the embeddings of $K$ into the field of algebraic numbers ($n$ is the degree of $K$). Now, in our case the field is quadratic, so there exist exactly two embeddings, and the conjugates of $\sqrt{-p}$ are exactly $\sqrt{-p}, - \sqrt{-p}$. Equivalently, using your definition of norm, take $b=2, a=-1$.

Comment: How do you know that $R/P$ is a ring with $p$ elements?

Comment: It's the definition of norm of an ideal.

Comment: ok and finally, I can't see $Q=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}] \cap P$

Comment: You are right: this is non trivial. However there exists an easier argument to prve that $(\sqrt{-p})$ is a prime ideal. Can you see that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]/(\sqrt{-p}) \cong \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: No, but I suppose that I have to use the first isomorphism theorem...